# Openstack Dashboard Horizon - Empty reply from server

Tags: server, 22.04, apache2, openstack

I’m trying to do a manual installation of Openstack following the documentation (https://docs.openstack.org/2023.2/#install-guides). I have successfully installed keystone, placement, glance, nova and neutron, validating their correct operation. I have reached the point of installing the horizon dashboard but, after carefully following the guide at https://docs.openstack.org/horizon/2023.2/install/install-ubuntu.html, when I run

> curl http://controller/horizon

I get ‘curl: (52) Empty reply from server’.

This is the /etc/apache2/conf-available/openstack-dashboard.conf file:

```
WSGIScriptAlias /horizon /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard/wsgi.py process-group=horizon
WSGIDaemonProcess horizon user=horizon group=horizon processes=3 threads=10 display-name=%{GROUP}
WSGIProcessGroup horizon
WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}

Alias /static /var/lib/openstack-dashboard/static/
Alias /horizon/static /var/lib/openstack-dashboard/static/

<Directory /usr/share/openstack-dashboard/openstack_dashboard>
  Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/lib/openstack-dashboard/static>
  Require all granted
</Directory>
```

This is the result of the

> openstack endpoint list

command:

```
+----------------------------------+-----------+--------------+--------------+---------+-----------+-----------------------------+
| ID                               | Region    | Service Name | Service Type | Enabled | Interface | URL                         |
+----------------------------------+-----------+--------------+--------------+---------+-----------+-----------------------------+
| 089f4ec78b1949cd9a975e7077805c6f | RegionOne | placement    | placement    | True    | public    | http://controller:8778      |
| 09af316f551a4a75a96c5ddb539acb0a | RegionOne | keystone     | identity     | True    | admin     | http://controller:5000/v3/  |
| 10c9cd76aa9c4499932e3d3a9be78de4 | RegionOne | placement    | placement    | True    | admin     | http://controller:8778      |
| 15444d9bcc5e4495a7eff40c5b50beec | RegionOne | nova         | compute      | True    | admin     | http://controller:8774/v2.1 |
| 2c05e0d4a333442eaf934a5b6f99a603 | RegionOne | neutron      | network      | True    | admin     | http://controller:9696      |
| 359495c32c3349749027d63d5db26863 | RegionOne | neutron      | network      | True    | public    | http://controller:9696      |
| 40c337b6c2834f4991a14e68934ad1c8 | RegionOne | neutron      | network      | True    | internal  | http://controller:9696      |
| 54269311db1947c59ed2d063358ddef7 | RegionOne | glance       | image        | True    | public    | http://controller:9292      |
| 78621c8b76424ecca8a8d54b370050ae | RegionOne | placement    | placement    | True    | internal  | http://controller:8778      |
| 817c3cfa988440cc8b98e01a92ef64e7 | RegionOne | keystone     | identity     | True    | internal  | http://controller:5000/v3/  |
| 988877fb44404352a0411eb5aeda55ed | RegionOne | glance       | image        | True    | admin     | http://controller:9292      |
| a9d30185ded34bdb8c68823e05709086 | RegionOne | nova         | compute      | True    | internal  | http://controller:8774/v2.1 |
| ab6aec4383484dce912f401778146e3a | RegionOne | glance       | image        | True    | internal  | http://controller:9292      |
| d42f705a0f894b9f9157736265aa478c | RegionOne | keystone     | identity     | True    | public    | http://controller:5000/v3/  |
| f5bb7ab5707e43b396a0602afe787b21 | RegionOne | nova         | compute      | True    | public    | http://controller:8774/v2.1 |
+----------------------------------+-----------+--------------+--------------+---------+-----------+-----------------------------+
```

This is the result of the

> apache2ctl -S

command:

```
VirtualHost configuration:
*:5000                 controller (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/keystone.conf:3)
*:8778                 controller (/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/placement-api.conf:3)
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"
Mutex default: dir="/var/run/apache2/" mechanism=default
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

I’m sure I’m missing something in the apache configurations, even though the documentation doesn’t mention anything else. Does anyone know how I can solve this?

Thank you in advance.

P.S. I'm using Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS